# Fog computing with veins

Tags: cloud, omnet++, veins, inet, fog

Can fog computing be used with veins and inet for an omnet++ project?
I want to build an omnet++ project, in which I can send and receive messages between OBUs and RSUs, but with RSU as a fog node in a fog area of other fog areas of the network

Answer (score 0):

fognetsimpp project is an omnet++ project that includes fog nodes. It includes both static and mobile nodes. Further details can be found on the fognetsimpp github page

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHEkiPnsIRE has video tutorial on the same project.

Comment: Another interesting project is ECSNet++, based on OMNET++. It has a detailed model of stream processing generated at edge nodes.